# Deserialization error when attribute is bool

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a xml into a class but it's giving me an exception.

My class is something like that:

```
public class FieldsVO
    {    
        public bool AllowPrint { get; set; }
        public bool AllowAbort { get; set; }
        public bool AllowPrintFSFSDA { get; set; }
    }
```

And my XML:

```
<fields>
    <AllowPrint>True</AllowPrint>
    <AllowAbort>True</AllowAbort>
    <AllowPrintFSFSDA>True</AllowPrintFSFSDA>
</fields>
```

The only way that the deserialization works is if the attributes are "string".
There is any way to do it with anotations or something?

Here's the deserialization code:

```
public static object Deserialize(string xml, Type objType)
        {
            if (false == xml.StartsWith("<"))
            {
                int pos = xml.IndexOf('<');
                xml = xml.Remove(0, pos);
            }
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(objType);
            XmlReaderSettings set = new XmlReaderSettings();
            set.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes;
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), set))
                return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

Comment: Post the actual (De)Serialization code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman just added the code.

Comment: Sigh. And now the Serialization code please. They have to match. And the XmlSerializer writes `true`, not `True`.

Comment: Yeah, the True was the problem. I didn't create the XML, I was just using it from a client's database.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to parse XML, you should use XSD Schema.

XSD Schema describes a XML file.

For add this file:
create an element -> XML Schema.
Call this file fields.xsd.

In your case, it will be:

```
<xs:element name="fields">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="AllowPrint" type="xs:boolean"/>
   <xs:element name="AllowAbort" type="xs:boolean"/>
   <xs:element name="AllowPrintFSFSDA" type="xs:boolean"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Then, open the command-line interface. go to the directory where the fields.xsd is.
enter:

```
xsd fields.xsd /classes
```

fields.cs is now generate.

In your XML file, you have to add:
 - the namespace of the XSD Schema
 - the location of the XSD Schema

```
      xmlns="urn:fields"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:fields fields.xsd">
```

Comment: You don't really need all that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's a very good habit to use XSD Schema when you work on your own XML. It's viable security. Its check the XML and generate the class. This powerfull tool has to be used.

Comment: It sometimes has to be used. Care to tell me where an XSD would help when using XmlSerializer?